# pdf generation using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg

I have been trying to code some **pdf-generator** using [svgToPdf](https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/). Now first I need to test the code. But there is not much documentation /demo over here. I am new to javascript. So I just want you guys to explain me how to use the code. The main idea is pretty simple though- it stores all the svg data in an array and as per the information associated with svg images it generates the pdf(places the images at proper position).

- What is the meaning of the [usage](https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/) over here?( I can't understand this)
- Can any of you give me a complete example or explain how to probably use it?

  Okay! what I am trying to do? [my_code](http://pastebin.com/mWD9pYwj). I wanted to see my whole page printed.(blue box+ hello world).

Comment: The **usage** above gives a complete example on how to use it. This looks like browser based code. Are you not familiar on how to use javascript in your html?

Comment: It looks like `pdf.output('datauri')` returns a string in the data url format. So you can do with it what you want. Currently you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: @slebetman.: No I am new in this javascript programming. Can you please point out the errors in my code.

Comment: @slebetman.: No I just want to show the generated pdf. When clicking the `print` link it is giving a blank page. What about the blue rectangle box? I mean it should print it..isn't it?

Comment: @slebetman.: I have tried to use it but not getting the result as desired. I just want to create a preview of a pdf-page. Now the here I will consider that the code will run (html file+js) on the html code itself. So the blue svg box must be there in the pdf but it generates a blank pdf.